# What is the UWP Async work running sequence

Tags: uwp, c++-winrt

I'm curious if the work submitted by `CoreDispatcher::RunAsync` is running in FIFO order. It seems I can't find the document about this. Can someone clarify this for me ? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm curious if the work submitted by CoreDispatcher::RunAsync is running in FIFO order.

It seems that the documentation does not specify that CoreDispatcher::RunAsync runs in FIFO order. But we can find [`ProcessEvents`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher.processevents?view=winrt-19041) method explanation. *Starts the dispatcher processing the input event **queue** for this instance of CoreWindow.*

And the queue represents a first-in, first-out collection of objects. So we can regard `CoreDispatcher::RunAsync` as running in FIFO order.

Update1

as @IInspectable comments below,  `CoreDispatcher::RunAsync` contains a [`CoreDispatcherPriority`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.coredispatcherpriority?view=winrt-19041) argument. And we often use `Normal` *priority that delegates are processed in the order they are scheduled.*

Comment: *"Queue"* does not imply FIFO. Since [CoreDispatcher::RunAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher.runasync) takes a `CoreDispatcherPriority` argument, it is reasonable to assume, that the queue is a *priority* queue. The relative order of events with the same priority is unspecified.

Comment: @IInspectable : "The relative order of events with the same priority is unspecified.". Sorry for my bad English. Does this mean works in the same queue will not run FIFO?

Comment: It implies that work dispatched with the same priority will run FIFO, though those dispatched with higher priority may run first